# Program to download pdf from google using google search

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i code a program which you give him the topic you want to download pdf of it , but it's not working well, so could anyone help me with that

```
from googlesearch import search
from pathlib import Path
import requests
extension = "ext:pdf"
query = "school time" + extension
for result in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    print(result)
pdfnum = 0
    filename = Path(pdfnum + ".pdf")
    url = result
    response=requests.get(url)
    filename.write_bytes(response.content) 
    pdfnum = pdfnum + 1
```

[The Error Message is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py7cm.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to describe what isn't working. Include an error message if there is any

Comment: The requests module isn't imported unless the googlesearch module isn't. Therefore this code will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python relies on indentation to determine which code block a statement belongs to (like C and Java rely on '{}'). You should try removing the indentation in the first 3 lines of your code. Their beginning should be aligned to lines 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you solved 2 of 4 errors but there is still 2, i eddited the code and i attached the error message, could you take alook at this

Comment: As the error message suggests, the line `pdfnum = 0` should be indented to line up with the others. This should fix all the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed indentation and type error in line 9. This code works for me:

```
from googlesearch import search
from pathlib import Path
import requests
extension = "ext:pdf"
query = "school time" + extension
pdfnum = 0
for result in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
  print(result)
  filename = Path(str(pdfnum) + ".pdf")
  url = result
  response=requests.get(url)
  filename.write_bytes(response.content) 
  pdfnum = pdfnum + 1
```